# I want to check whether the document id specified by me exists or not

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to fetch the number first from firebase auth in a varibale name globalNumber which is set as document id in firebase and then use that to check whether the doc id exists or not. If exists then Navigate to some page else navigate to some other page as shown in my code. But its not working perfectly may the number is not being fetched correctly or there might be some other issue. I have checked some other similar question but its not working for me. Could anyone please let me know the correct code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:loginpage/AccountDetialsPage.dart';

import 'package:loginpage/Pricepage.dart';



class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  var globalNumber;
  var firestore;
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
    firestore = Firestore.instance;

  }

  getCurrentUser() async{

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    globalNumber = user.phoneNumber;

}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print(globalNumber);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Center(child: (Text('Welcome '))),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: 50,
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: (Text('Next',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
              onPressed: () async{
                final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(globalNumber).get();

                if (snapShot.exists){
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              Pricepage()
                      ));
                }
                else{
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              AccountDetialsPage()
                      ));
                }

              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Question**

How can I check whether the document id specified by me exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 onPressed: () async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    var globalNumb = user.phoneNumber;
    final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(globalNumb).get();
    if (snapShot.exists){
            //..
```

inside `onPressed` retrieve the current user `phoneNumber` and then using `exists` check if the document exists or not.